# How can i implement a multi file upload with size greater than 200MB

Tags: upload

I want to know if its possible to upload files to my site greater than 200MB.

Comment: What language/context? What have you tried?

Comment: we cant help you till you specify the language you are using..

Answer (score 4):

## Yes, it is possible.​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​

Comment: Kindly can guide me to a free source where i can use it.i know one called uploadify but i always face the upload size issue.

Comment: I think the font size should be much bigger in this case.

Comment: @zalmai: It _completely_ depends on your server.

Comment: @zalmai: you can try 3rd party service, e.g. https://uploadcare.com